# I'm unable to create angular project using VS code terminal

Tags: angular, installation, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm trying to install Angular through CLI. Firstly I install node js v12.18.2 and npm version v6.14.5. I'm able to run a command on command prompt to create the angular app but when I'm trying to run the command to create angular app on the VS code terminal it is showing an error:

**'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

[image: Console showing ng serve]

Comment: Was there meant to be an image in your question? It wasn't included properly so I've removed the text about the image description, but you can edit your question to add an image if you want to.

Comment: Have you restarted VS-Code after installtion of `@angular/cli`? Also what OS do you use and what terminal (cmd, powershell, etc.)?

Comment: @kai yeah i restarted VS code. i'm using Windows 7 32bit.

Comment: @Tim i didn't have 10 reputations on my account  that's why image is not visible only URL will be there.

Comment: Thanks for adding the URL, I've added the image for you now.

Comment: Can you share the the screen-shot of the VS code terminal also. Perhaps it is not configured correctly.

Comment: @Tim thank you so much :)   but how you did ? please tell me.

Comment: @Praym thank you for your comment right now i didn't have screen shot of that error but i mentioned error in  bold format.

Comment: @ShivaniGoyal when you're writing/editing a question, there's a toolbar across the top of the edit box with various formatting tools. One of the icons is for inserting an image, and it sorts out all the right formatting for you. If you want to see what it looks like, click the Edit link for this question and take a look at the toolbar. (You don't have to save your edits if you're happy with the question as it stands, you'll be able to cancel them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Add the given path " C:\Users\rkota\AppData\Roaming\npm" in Environment variable.
Once done kindly restart app and re run npm install -g @angular/cli@latest and than ng command.

Comment: it is really helpfull. Thank you so much.